# UIToolbar title overlaps done button

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitoolbar

I'd like to create a UIToolbar with a right-aligned done button and a left-aligned title/label.

My current solution works fine for short labels but overlaps with long ones

With autolayout I'd set the horizontal spacing to 0 and make sure my `done` text has higher compression resistance than the title text. But using the UIToolbar api I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

[image: Overlap Issue]

Here's the code that generates this:

```
lazy var pickerToolbar: UIToolbar = {
  let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 33))
  let leftTitle = UIBarButtonItem(title: "One and only one with lots of choices", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  leftTitle.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  let space     = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
  let closeBtn  = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "onTapClose")
  toolbar.setItems([
    leftTitle,
    space,
    closeBtn
  ], animated: false)
  return toolbar
}()

// ...later
textField.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar
```

Comment: that is your textfield value